# How to send image data and other parameter using SOAP web service

Tags: iphone, ios, soap

I want to send image data over soap web service. My soap message as per mention below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<TestFile xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <userID>int</userID>
  <FileTitle>string</FileTitle>
  <FileName>string</FileName>
  <BufferFile>base64Binary</BufferFile>
  <languageID>int</languageID>
</TestFile>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and i want to add image over bufferFile with base64 encoding.

Give me any suggestion or sample code that can send maltipart data or parameters at same time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [SudzC](http://sudzc.com/), which will generate client code for iOS, to communicate with your WebService. In your case, it will generate a method, with parameters you need to pass. All you need to have is a WSDL.